# Line print in python

Tags: python

I am using Python 3 and Pycharm 2021.3. I want to **print "4" on the first line**. And **"3" on the second line**. I wrote code like this:

```
a="4"
b="3"
print(a\n,b)
```

It show a Error message. Please tell me the right way to write this. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `print(a + "\n" + b)`

Answer (score 1):

```py
print(a + "\n" + b)
```

Or

```py
print(a)
print(b)
```

Or

```py
print(a, b, sep="\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to explicitly add a new line, you should use `"\n"`, like you did. However, you mustn't forget that this is a character, so you need to surround it by " or '.

Next, when you want to **concatenate** string variables, the standard is the use of `+`.

Put together, if you want to concatenate three variables, in which one of them is a string, a possible way would be:

```
final = a + '\n' + b
print(final)
```